# Could not find site url while saving document to SharePoint on the fly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-integration, save

I have a SharePoint 2013 farm on which there is a team site. We have few document libraries in which we are trying to save our document/excel or any other office file directly.

My client machine is having Windows 7 and Office 2010. Below are the steps which we are performing:

1. Open Excel File and created a new workbook.
2. Go To File -> Save & Send -> Save to SharePoint -> Browse for a site url with document library. eg: `http://www.contoso.com/sites/test/Documents/Firm ABC`
3. Provide the credentials and save the document with some name.
4. Close the excel file
5. Create new workbook **(Till here everything is working fine)**
6. Go To File -> Save & Send -> Save to SharePoint -> Select the location from recent history

Now as soon as I select the location it gives me the error

> Could not find `http://www.contoso.com/sites/test/Documents/Firm%20ABC`

Do anyone have idea why it is behaving like this? My guess is %20 is making problem because when I am trying to add the file in a folder (whose name doesn't have space) it's not giving any error.